# Command cannot be recognized

Tags: linux, centos, containerd, nerdctl, almalinux

I wanted to ask a likely very simple question regarding Linux (AlmaLinux-9.2)...

I unpacked the file and I wanted to execute the binary file `nerdctl`. However, I could not do it if I did not add `./` at the beginning of the command?

[image]

It is because I need to move or link up this file to another folder `/usr/local/bin`, so it can be globally used.
But, how can I execute the file without adding `./`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, the reason you need to use `./` before executing a binary in the current directory is related to the `PATH` environment variable. The `PATH` variable tells the shell which directories to search for executable files.

The `./` before a command indicates to the shell to look in the current directory for the executable. By default, the current directory (`.`) is usually not part of the `PATH` for security reasons. If it were, malicious binaries could be disguised with common command names in directories, and you could inadvertently run them.

If you want to run the `nerdctl` command from any location without prefixing with `./`, you have a few options:

1. **Move or Symlink to a Directory in `$PATH`**:
   Most system-wide binaries are stored in directories that are included in the `PATH` variable, such as `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc. If you move or symlink your binary to one of these directories, you can call it from anywhere without the `./` prefix.

   ```bash
   sudo mv nerdctl /usr/local/bin/
   ```

   OR

   ```bash
   sudo ln -s /path/to/your/nerdctl /usr/local/bin/nerdctl
   ```
2. **Modify the `PATH` Variable**:
   This is less recommended because it can introduce the security issues mentioned above, but you could add the directory containing `nerdctl` to the `PATH` variable.

   Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (depending on your shell):

   ```bash
   export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/directory
   ```